# Is it possible to upload images from upload form by chosing images from facebook?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I have to make an facebook app where I have an upload form with two inputs of type file. First input of type file is for uploading an image through PHP. After this comes my big problem.

I have the second input from where I should be able to choose a photo from facebook to upload.

I googled a lot, and found no answer to my question.

Now, I now that after I get user permissions like this:

```
$userinfo = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,email,last_name,first_name,albums,picture,photos');
```

I can have the images URL's of the user that gave permissions to enter the app.

What I don't know and didn't found anywhere is how to choose and upload what photo I want into my database, from my profile, through PHP.

Is this even possible?!

How can I at least simulate the normal upload like when using normal PHP way?!

I don't want anyone to do my job for me, I just need a start point.

Comment: you would need to list albums, select one and list photos. example code is in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/albums/

Comment: ...and the photos per album: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/album/photos

Comment: I've came across those links. Didn't help. To little documentation.

Comment: then you should start at the very beginning: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ - the link to the album would be enough information if you already know how the graph api works, it even includes example code for many languages. either way, your question is a bit too broad. it´s unclear what your question actually is...you get the albums and photos with the graph api, after that you can do whatever you want with the resulting data...